# Customization of Error Message Display in Struts2

Tags: struts2

i am validating user input in my application using Struts2 build in validation framework and its working fine.
I have to show the error message as per the application layout so need to place my  inside a predefined block.
but i need to show this block only when there is validation error in my application and i am unable to figure out how i can do this.

One solution is i should override the theme for error but in that case error theme will applicable for whole application and that is not what i need.Is there any way by whihc i can check if  contains any error or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.after looking at free marker template i came up with solution
something like

```
fieldErrors.keySet().size()
```